# FBSDKGraphRequest FBSDKGraphRequestConnection only in iOS 9 return error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios9, parsefacebookutils

this is the login success with iOS 9.0.1.

[image]

this is the login failed with iOS 9 iPhone .

[image]

and in iOS 9 iPhone i have this warning :

[image]

the sdk update to parse 1.8.5 and Facebook to 4.6 from here :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

what can I do to solved this ?

the Facebook login is with PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions :

```
  NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"user_friends", nil];
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!user) // The user cancelled the Facebook login
     {
         NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
     }
     else if (user.isNew) 
     {

     }
     else if (user) // the user is exist at DB
     {

     }
     else if (error)
     {
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u added this params in yout plist?

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>YourFBKey</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>moodoo</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
```